# jq - search a string value at any level of a json file and get the parent keys

Tags: json, nested, jq

I would like to find in a JSON file a specific value (without worrying about the key) at any level of my JSON file (I don't know in advance the exact tree) and display the parent keys.

I have extracted this sample :

```
cat /tmp/test.json | jq
{
  "totalCount": 2,
  "pageSize": 1000,
  "auditLogs": [
    {
      "logId": "169807591200060002",
      "eventType": "CREATE",
      "category": "CONFIG",
      "entityId": "HTTP_CHECK-12121212121212",
      "timestamp": 1698075912003,
      "success": true,
      "patch": [
        {
          "op": "replace",
          "path": "/",
          "value": {
            "steps": [
              {
                "id": {
                  "type": "HTTP_CHECK_STEP"
                },
                "requestType": "OAUTH2",
                "destinationUrl": "https://www.mywebsite.com",
                "httpMethod": "POST",
                "acceptAnyCertificate": true,
                "followRedirects": true,
                "displayName": "My Website",
                "userAgent": "",
                "httpCheckHeaders": [
                  {
                    "name": "Content-Type",
                    "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                  }
                ],
                "stepPerformanceThreshold": 0,
                "requestBody": null,
                "constraints": [
                  {
                    "constraintType": "HttpStatusesList",
                    "passIfFound": false,
                    "pattern": ">=400"
                  }
                ],
                "preScript": "",
                "postScript": "",
                "attributes": {
                  "oAuth2RequestId": "1",
                  "oAuth2BodyInputType": "RAW",
                  "oAuth2addAuthDataTo": "REQUEST_BODY"
                },
                "postExecutionScriptVariables": [
                  "{bearerToken-1}"
                ],
                "preExecutionScriptVariables": [],
                "certificateId": "",
                "basicAuthId": "",
                "certStoreId": 0,
                "basicAuthStoreId": 0,
                "authenticationConfig": {
                  "type": "BASIC_AUTHENTICATION",
                  "realmName": null,
                  "kdcIp": null,
                  "credentialId": "CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121"
                },
                "executionProperties": {},
                "shouldNotPersistSensitiveData": true
              }
            ],
            "publicLocationIds": [
              124
            ],
            "userModificationTimestamp": 1698075911987,
            "customProperties": [],
            "version": 6
          },
          "oldValue": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "logId": "169807591200060001",
      "eventType": "CREATE",
      "category": "CONFIG",
      "entityId": "HTTP_CHECK-12121212121212",
      "environmentId": "b416bf43-a9d2-4123-aa70-e36ff39c0ad9",
      "timestamp": 1698075911986,
      "success": true,
      "patch": [
        {
          "op": "replace",
          "path": "/",
          "value": {
            "frequency (Frequency)": 0,
            "locations": [
              {
                "location (Location)": "SYNTHETIC_LOCATION-000000000000007C"
              }
            ]
          },
          "oldValue": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am able to find the string "CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121" with this recursive command :

```
cat /tmp/test.json | jq '.auditLogs[] | .. | .credentialId? | select(. == "CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121")'                       
"CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121"
```

But I would like also to get the parent key "logId" at the first level. I tried to use a variable ($parent) but unfortunately I got several results instead of only one :

```
cat /tmp/test.json | jq '.auditLogs[] as $parent | .. | .credentialId? | select(. == "CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121") | $parent | {"logId":.logId}'
{
  "logId": "169807591200060002"
}
{
  "logId": "169807591200060001"
}
```

Does anyone have an idea for this need?

Comment: Can you clarify what the desired output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `paths` to find the paths with matching values, extract from it the first two items (`["auditLogs",0]` in this case), use `getpath` to retrieve that object, and extract `.logId` from there:

```bash
jq -r 'getpath(paths(. == "CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121")[:2]).logId'
```

```
169807591200060002
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/c1VCzL86bMg)

If you want objects containing only the `logId` field, use `{logId}` instead:

```bash
jq 'getpath(paths(. == "CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121")[:2]) | {logId}'
```

```json
{
  "logId": "169807591200060002"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jBDVPurmrc3)

You can also consider collecting the results in an array by wrapping `[…]` around the filter. Or use the `--arg` option to import the search key from the command line, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> ... without worrying about the key

> ... I don't know in advance the exact tree

Here's a straightforward approach that meets both these requirements (and I'd hazard is faster than using `paths` and `getpath`):

```
.. | objects
| select(.logId)
| .logId as $id
| .. | objects
| select(.[] == "CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121")
| $id
```

Since the string might occur several times, you might want to consider variants, for example replacing the second-last line above by:

```
| select(first(.[] == "CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121" // empty))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IN`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#sql-style-operators) (or `any(stream; condition)`):

```
.auditLogs[]
| select(IN(.. | .credentialId?; "CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121"))
| .logId
```

or, depending on your output format requirements:

```
.auditLogs[]
| select(IN(.. | .credentialId?; "CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121"))
| { logId }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers. I finally chose to use the first solution using the getpath() function. With this solution, we don’t care about the name of the key. Indeed in my case the pattern to search ("CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121") is not necessary the value of the key "credentialId". This can be another key:

```
$ grep "CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121" auditlogs2.json
                  "credentialId": "CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121"
                  "myotherkey": "CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121"

$ cat auditlogs2.json | jq -r 'getpath(paths(. == "CREDENTIALS_VAULT-1212121212121")[:2]) | .logId'
169807591200060002
169807591200060001
```

Both entries were found. That is more appropriate in my case ;)
But thanks again to every one.